# Make a collapsible expand over the content beneath it

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I'm trying to create a collapsible that, when expanded, should roll over the content beneath it. So the content beneath it stays in place.

```
 <div data-role="collapsible">
     <h3>Content of collapsible</h3>
     <ul data-role="listview">
         <li>I'm the collapsible set content.</li>
         <li>I should roll over the data beneath me.</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
 <div>
     <p>I'm data underneath.</p>
     <p>I should remain in place when the collapsible is unfolded.</p>
 </div>
```

Sample code in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/3swM6/

Possibly I'm using the wrong approach to achieve this.

Comment: so you want the data beneath to be hidden by the expanded content?

Comment: you need to fix it when collapsible expands and unfix it when it collapses http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3swM6/2/

Comment: Yes. A little more info about how I want to use this: in my web project the listview contains options to choose from. On selection the collapsible listview closes again. The expanded listview doesn't cover up all the data underneath, in case this is what you are wondering about.

Comment: Thanks Omar, but it will be simpler to solve this with CSS rules provided by Newbo.O and Jake!

Comment: Yup, CSS solution is easier, I'm not a CSS guru ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this effect you need to set the position of the content that you want to "stick".

Here's a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jakemulley/xU6Pv/

I used the following CSS:

```
.hider .ui-collapsible-content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks Jake, this seems much more easier to solve then I thought. I'm going to implement asap.

Answer (score 1):

You just need these CSS rules on the collapsible content generated by jQueryMobile:

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
```

Here's a working example from your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3swM6/1/

Comment: Thanks Newbo.O, you and Jake posted the same good solution seconds apart from each other. So it is a though decision for me to pick the answer. I give it to Jake cause he seems to be starting on building his reputation. Also he did a little more typing by using 2 css selectors. Hope you don't mind.